# MVVMCross Data Binding after returning from ViewController

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am using MVVMCross 3.2.2 as part of an iOS/Android app.   One of my screens has multiple views that are displayed depending upon the selection in a Tab bar like row of buttons.  Different data is displayed in each of these these views individual UITableView.  The data binding works perfectly.

I also have a menu, that has a "profile" selection.  Changing the profile fires an MvxMessage that my HomeView receives and then uses the message to set the ViewModel up to filter the data to be displayed. This all seems to work perfectly and the data is displayed correctly.

If I do something in the HomeView that displays another view using ShowViewModel().  When I return back to the home view the binding no longer works properly when a profile changes is made.  The message gets handled, the data gets filtered, but a call to ReloadDataTable on the UITableView does not change the data.

**ViewModel**

```
    #region Groupings
    public IList<Group> Groups{
        get { return _groupService.GetAll(); }
    }

    public void SetupSubGroups(Group group)
    {
        if (group == null)
        {
            _groups = new ObservableCollection<Group> ();
            if (_profileService.SelectedProfile != null)
            {
                var grp = _groupService.GetByGroupName (_profileService.SelectedProfile.Name);
                if (grp == null)
                    grp = new Group { Name = _profileService.SelectedProfile.Name };
                _groups.Add (grp);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var litsOfGroups = _groupService.GetSubGroups (group);
            foreach (var grp in litsOfGroups)
                _groups.Add (grp);
        }
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => AvailableGroups);
    }

    private ObservableCollection <Group> _groups;

    public ObservableCollection<Group> AvailableGroups {
        get { return _groups; }
    }
    #endregion
```

**ViewController**

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        var groupSource = new GroupTableViewDataSource (TableViewGroups);
        TableViewGroups.Source = groupSource;

        _localViewModel.SetupSubGroups (null);

        _bindingSet = this.CreateBindingSet<HomeViewController, HomeViewModel> ();
        _bindingSet.Bind (groupSource).To (vm => vm.AvailableGroups);
        _bindingSet.Apply ();
        TableViewReportTags.ReloadData ();

        NavigationController.NavigationBarHidden = false;
    }


    private void OnProfileChanged(ProfileChangedMessage message)
    {
        _localViewModel.SetupSubGroups (null);
        TableViewGroups.ReloadData ();
    }

    private HomeViewModel _localViewModel { get { return ViewModel as HomeViewModel; } }
```

Any ideas what I can look at, or change would be really useful.  I have spend many hours on this, and have made no progress.

Comment: Looking at the question I don't understand what `_localViewModel` is - and I also don't understand why `base.ViewDidLoad` is called after the binding has been applied... can you edit the question to include a more complete sample?

Comment: _localViewModel is a private cast of ViewModel from IMvxViewModel that is used within the View for cleaner looking access to methods in the ViewModel ---- private HomeViewModel _localViewModel { get { return ViewModel as HomeViewModel; } }

Comment: I have moved the base.ViewDidLoad() up, to no avail.

Comment: Still no idea from the code you have posted. Does the ListView in N=17 work for you? https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/N-17-CollectABull-Part6/CollectABull.Touch/Views/ListView.cs - that's a similar viewmodel refreshed by a message. Can you build a simple self-contained sample which shows the "broken binding" happening? Is there any trace to show the broken binding? If you add your own trace at the end of OnProfileChanged` does `_localViewModel.AvailableGroups` contain the data you expect it to?

Comment: I haven't tried the N=17, but will have a look at it.  Yes at the end of OnProfileChanged the data I expect is contained within _localViewModel.AvailableGroups.  It get displayed correctly every time until I meow to another View and come back, then the data is never refreshed after process OnProfileChanged.

Comment: @Stuart. Thanks for all your help on this. Sorry I haven't been able to provide all the source you needed to investigate the issue I was experienced.  I have managed to rewrite my code and made the profile choices execute a ShowViewModel<>() method instead of using the MvxMessage approach. As a result my problem has gone.

Comment: Moderators ...  This question can be closed